# Rolling Regression Window for each element in a List in R

Tags: r, list, time-series, regression, rolling-computation

I have a list with this structure in R:

[image: My list, in each element i have all the elements necessary for the regressions]

My list has the date and the variables for the regression. "re" needs to be the dependant variable and "mkt" the independent variable, so re~mkt
So i would like to apply the same rolling window regression in each element.

I want to do a rolling window regression for 60 observations (and at least for 40 observations), moving forward month by month. For example, suppose that one element starts their observations in January-2000 until April-2020. So my goal is to do the first regression for the first 60 observations (january-2000 to december-2004, the next observation between february-2000 until january 2005, and so on). So 1-60, 2-61, 3-62, 4-63...
It's important to highlight the feature of "at least 40 observations". Not all element in the list have more than 60 observations, so the minimum to do the regression has to be 40. If an element of the list have less than 60 i want to do with at least 40 (but if the list have 50 with 50 observations). If there are no more than 40 i want the same output but with NA.

I hope it was understood well enough. Tell me any question.

I have the code to do the rolling regression with 60 observations, but i do not know how to apply the "at least for 40 observations" and i do not know how to apply the code to the list.

The code for the rolling is only for a trial sample.

```
# window size
window <- 60

# to save mkt coefficients
coefs_mkt <- numeric()

##Loop
# Iterar a través de las ventanas móviles
for (i in 1:(nrow(prueba) - window + 1)) {
  # Seleccionar la ventana móvil actual
  current_window <- prueba[i:(i + window - 1), ]
  
  # Ajustar el modelo de regresión
  model <- lm(re ~ mkt, data = current_window)
  
  # Guardar el coeficiente de mkt en el vector
  coefs_mkt <- c(coefs_mkt, coef(model)["mkt"])
}

print(coefs_mkt)
```

Don't worry if the code is so different, i suppose that there are better ways to do that.

Comment: Please note the posting instructions at the top of the R [tag:r] tag page and in particular that questions should include a minimal reproducible example not using images and instead using `dput` so that others can run it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but it's far from the most efficient and correct way to do it, but I tried to follow your style

```
price_list <- list(ACX.MC=list(re=rnorm(368), mkt=rnorm(368)))

df <- data.frame(re=price_list$ACX.MC$re , mkt=price_list$ACX.MC$mkt)

window <-  60
coefs_mkt <- rep(NA, nrow(df))

for(i in window:nrow(df)){
  ii <- (i-(window-1)):i
  model <- lm(re ~ mkt, data = df[ii,])
  coefs_mkt[i] <- coef(model)["mkt"]
}
```

here is another option for effective calculation in c++

```
devtools::install_version("rollRegres", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")

window <-  60

library(rollRegres)
out <- roll_regres(re ~ mkt, df, width = window)

print(out$coefs[,"mkt"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example using the built in `BOD` data frame. coefs takes a matrix with column Time and demand and outputs the coefficients of a linear regression using `flm`.  `roll` rolls  coefs down a data frame with a window of 4 using `rollapplyr` where the r on the end means right aligned. `rollapplyr` uses the argument `partial=3` which says it requires at least 3 points and otherwise `fill=NA` specifies that we get NA back.  In your case the 4 would be 60 and the 3 would be 40.

```
library(collapse) # flm
library(zoo) # rollapplyr

# test data
L <- list(A = BOD, B = BOD)

coefs <- function(x) c(flm(formula = demand ~ Time, data = as.data.frame(x)))
roll <- function(x) rollapplyr(x, 4, coefs, partial = 3, fill = NA, 
  by.column = FALSE)

Map(roll, L)
```

giving:

```
$A
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,]        NA        NA
[2,]        NA        NA
[3,]  1.833333 5.3500000
[4,]  5.450000 3.1800000
[5,] 10.710000 1.2900000
[6,] 15.862857 0.3657143

$B
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,]        NA        NA
[2,]        NA        NA
[3,]  1.833333 5.3500000
[4,]  5.450000 3.1800000
[5,] 10.710000 1.2900000
[6,] 15.862857 0.3657143
```